# Issue exists in auto generation of number sequence AX

Tags: axapta, data-import, data-management, dynamics-ax7, d3fo

I have been trying to import customer master through data management tool in AX7 using "Customers" standard data entity, I have marked "Auto-Generate" for customer account field. And I am facing a number sequence error while the data gets inserted into staging.  When I check the execution log I see the below error.

> "Issue exists in auto generation of number sequence
>              Issue exist in generate staging data
>              '4' 'Customers' record(s) inserted in staging"

I checked number sequence setup for Customer account and it is proper it is as below:

[image]

Note:

Gives the same error irrespective of Continuous is marked or not for the number sequence code.

Any quick inputs would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to debug this error? What does your staging data look like, specifically the customer account number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Fh-Inway!
I have figured out the issue, and it's an issue with standard AX. An application hot fix (Metadata) is available for this which can be found in the LCS as a part of AX update2. I have installed it, tested it to be working fine. 
Not sure whether I can share the Hotfix KB Article number here for the same.

Note: That hotfix has a common fix that addresses auto-generation of number sequences across all the data entities.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see no reason why you should not include the hotfix KB number here.

Comment: This is it: KB 3192302 Importing data with auto generated columns (number sequence based) fails  :)